# How to match full words and not substrings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my code

```
stopwordlist = "a|an|all"
File.open('0_9.txt').each do |line|
line.downcase!
line.gsub!( /\b#{stopwordlist}\b/,'')
File.open('0_9_2.txt', 'w') { |f| f.write(line) }
end
```

I wanted to remove words - a,an and all
But, instead it matches substrings also and removes them

For an example input -

```
Bromwell High is a cartoon comedy. It ran at the same time as some other programs about school life
```

I get the output -

```
bromwell high is  cartoon comedy. it r t the same time s some other programs bout school life
```

As you can see, it matched the substring.

How do I make it just match the word and not substrings ?

Comment: Change the word list so they can't be in the middle of a word (e.g. "an ", " an.")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `|` operator in regex takes the widest scope possible. Your original regex matches either `\ba` or `an` or `all\b`.

Change the whole regex to:

```
/\b(?:#{stopwordlist})\b/
```

or change `stopwordlist` into a regex instead of a string.

```
stopwordlist = /a|an|all/
```

Even better, you may want to use `Regexp.union`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\ba\b|\ban\b|\ball\b
```

try this.this will look for word boundaries.